# firebase + react, setState does not seem to trigger re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase as a backend and am working on a detail view for a Restaurant entity. A restaurant has an array of dish ids and based on this I want to list the dishes when viewing the restaurant.

In the dish listing component, I get as props the array of dish ids. I then go through each of the dish ids and get the dish data from firebase. I do this in *componentWillReceiveProps* in order to get the latest state updates in the parent component.

Here's the Dish Listing Component:

```
class DishList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            Dishes: []
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        const tempDishes = []
        props.dishes.map(dish => {
            firebaseDishes.child(dish).on("value", snap => {
                if (tempDishes.findIndex(x => x.id === snap.key) == -1) {
                    // push only if id doesn't exist
                    tempDishes.push({
                        id: snap.key,
                        name: snap.val().name,
                        price: snap.val().price
                    })
                    this.setState({
                        Dishes: tempDishes
                    })
                } else {
                    const updatedTempDishes = tempDishes.slice()
                    updatedTempDishes[updatedTempDishes.findIndex(x => x.id === snap.key)] = {
                        id: snap.key,
                        name: snap.val().name,
                        price: snap.val().price
                    }
                    this.setState({
                        Dishes: updatedTempDishes
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="dishes">
            {
                this.state.Dishes.map(dish => {
                    return(
                        <DishListItem key={dish.id} 
                                    DishId={dish.id}
                                    DishName={dish.name} 
                                    DishPrice={dish.price}/>
                    )
                })
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here's the parent component:

```
class Place extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            Place: {
                name: '',
                address: '',
                dishes: []
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        firebasePlaces.child(this.props.placeId).on("value", snap => {
            this.setState({
                Place: snap.val()
            })
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 className="name"> {this.state.Place.name} </h1>
                <h3 className="address"> {this.state.Place.address} </h3>
                <DishList dishes={this.state.Place.dishes} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**What works:**

- the dish listing correctly populates on page load (1)

**What doesn't work:**

- if I update a dish on firebase it does not update the listing on the UI (2)

**What I have checked:**

- the callback functions correctly for the update, i.e. if I change a dish entry in firebase I get that data under snap.val()
- the state changes. If I check the state before the setState call and afterwards in the setState completion callback, I see the difference between the two states
- if I first empty the state and then in the completion callback set the state again using the new data, **it updates the UI**

Like this:

```
this.setState({
    Dishes: []
}, () => {
    this.setState({
        Dishes: updatedTempDishes
    })
})
```

Any hints to why this might be happening are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Inside your else condition, does updatedTempDishes  have the changes to the dish before setState?

Comment: @VijayMenon yes, updatedTempDishes has the changes to the dish.

Comment: can you share the parent component and render code as well?

Comment: @VijayMenon sure, I've edited my question.

Comment: Might you need to manually trigger a re-render?

Comment: Triggering a re-render in the setState completion callback doesn't seem to update the UI. The only thing that seems to work is to first empty the state, and then in the callback of that set the state again with the update values, as in my last code snippet.

Comment: @aandrei, Just one more doubt. Could it be because of a Shallow copy ? Is the response from firebase a deep nested Object? If so, you may have to do a deep copy by setting the individual keys seperately. Im just exploring all options.